# How to Get Clusterstate of SolrCloud with Spring Data Solr?

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I have a SolrCloud cluster and there are many Solr instances running within it. They are managed over a distributed Zookeeper ensemble.

Is there any way for Spring Solr data that will give external Zookeeper ensemble host names to a method so that we can retrieve the cluster state (i.e. clusterstate.json)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that:

```
CloudSolrServer solrServer;
...
solrServer.getZkStateReader().getClusterState();
...
```